# How to only send push notification to the receiver of the messages?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing an app, in Ionic 2, which uses Firebase to send push notifications based on the device token. However, I want it to send a push notification to the receiver and not also the sender - Now, it sends to both.

What my app does: When a user signs in, he gets a device token in Firebase, which is used to send him push notifications when he receives a message.

What I have tried: I have followed this [tutorial](http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-sending-push-notifications-to-specific-devices/).

This is the `index.js` in my `node_module`:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var wrotedata;
exports.Pushtrigger = functions.database.ref('/chat/{chatId}/messages/{messageId}').onWrite((event) => {
    wrotedata = event.data.val();

    admin.database().ref('/pushtokens').orderByChild('uid').once('value').then((alltokens) => {
        var rawtokens = alltokens.val();
        var tokens = [];
        processtokens(rawtokens).then((processedtokens) => {

            for (var token of processedtokens) {
                if(token!='') {
                tokens.push(token.devtoken);
                }
            }

        var payload = { 

                "notification":{
                    "title":"From: " + wrotedata.username,
                    "body":"Message: " + wrotedata.chat_text,
                    "sound":"default",
                    },
                "data":{
                    "sendername": wrotedata.username,
                    "message": wrotedata.chat_text
                }
        }      
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then((response) => {
                console.log('Pushed notifications');
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        })    
    })
})

function processtokens(rawtokens) {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         var processedtokens = []
    for (var token in rawtokens) {
        processedtokens.push(rawtokens[token]);
    }
    resolve(processedtokens);
    })
    return promise;    

}
```

- Thought: As I have the UID for both the sender and receiver, I'll need to check, before `tokens.push(token.devtoken);`, that the UID of the token isn't the sender's UID - I'm not sure how to implement that, but it's my suggestion. The function in my Firebase is triggered when a new message, in `'/chat/{chatId}/messages/{messageId}'`, is written

Comment: Do you have data mapping the username or some unique id for each user to their UID? If so you could pull the sender's UID from there and ensure it is not added to the list of tokens to be sent.

Comment: Each user only have a unique UID